# How can i filter by many-to-many field in other table Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My models:

```
class Job:
    id = models.UUIDField()
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)


class JobReviewers:
    user_id = models.UUIDField()
    name = models.CharField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='reviewers')

class Category:
    id = models.UUIDField()
```

I want to filter all job's where user is reviewer for job with name and category

```
user_id = uuid.uuid4()
all_jobs = Job.objects.all()
jobs_where_user_is_reviewer = ...
```

If it'll be filter just by name without category i can write this:

```
job_names_where_user_reviewer = JobReviewers.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).values('name', flat=True)
jobs_where_user_is_reviewer = all_jobs.filter(name__in=job_names_where_user_reviewer)
```

How can i do this with categories m2m field?

Comment: What do you want to filter in the category?

Comment: @AK i want to get job objects if the JobReviewers.categories contains Job category for current user

Comment: So the `Job`s name is `unique` and the `JobReviewer`s name essentially (always) refers to a valid `Job` name?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem it doesn't refer but may match, for example
`Job(name='test', ...), JobReviewers(user_id=..., name='test')`

Comment: But thus the `category` of the `Job` should be one of the items in the `categories` of `JobReviewers`, or is a `category` id given? If so, should it match for the `category` of the `Job`, the `JobReviewers`, or both?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem my mistake, of course `Job.category` is ForeignKey for the Category table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given I understand it correctly, you want to get `Job`s for which the `name` matches, and the `category` is in the `categories` of a `JobReviewers`, where `user_id` referes to a given `user_id`.

We can do this with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Job.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        JobReviewers.objects.filter(
            name=OuterRef('name'), categories=OuterRef('category'), user_id=user_id
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: @AnonymousWizard: I made a small typo, `name=OuterRef('name')`.

Comment: that's fine, i tried this way but used `categories__in=[OuterRef('category')]` and got a huge misunderstanding why this doesn't work

Comment: @AnonymousWizard: it is not necessary to use `__in`, each field you use in `foo__bar` is a *left outer join*, so `categories` is still a *single* category, or `NULL` if there is no related `Category`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
category_id = uuid.uuid4()
my_jobs = all_jobs.filter(name__in=job_names_where_user_reviewer, category__id=category_id)
```

Comment: What is `category_id`? We don't have it, categories where user is reviewer we can get only from JobReviewers if  `JobReviewers.user_id = user_id` and `Job.name = JobReviewers.name`, then we can take `JobReviewers.categories` and filter `Job` with it